# Call a stored procedure with an integer array as argument?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to pass an integer array as an argument to the stored procedure, how can this be done?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rd22(unitList INT)
 BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM abet INNER JOIN a ON a.id = abet.alarm_source 
    AND a.unit IN (unitList) 
    WHERE abet.begin_timestamp = 1395874800000;
END
```

This is how the stored proc looks like, and I want to achive something like this:

```
SET @val = [1,2,3];
CALL rd22(@val);
```

One way I can think is pass a string and then somehow convert it to integers. Is there any other subtle way to achive this.

Thanks for your time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this way, when you pass the param as comma separated string in the query it will only take the first value while executing the `in clause`, you need to use dynamic query with prepared statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rd22(unitList varchar(100))
 BEGIN
    set @ul = unitList;
    set @qry = concat("select * from abet INNER JOIN a ON a.id = abet.alarm_source and a.unit IN(",@ul,") WHERE abet.begin_timestamp = 1395874800000");    
    prepare stmt from @qry;
    execute stmt;    
END
```

The call will be as

```
SET @val = '1,2,3';
CALL rd22(@val);
```

Here is a test case in mysql

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| id   | created             | resolved            | status   |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|    1 | 2015-05-10 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | open     |
|    2 | 2015-05-10 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | new      |
|    3 | 2015-05-10 00:00:00 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00 | resolved |
|    4 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | open     |
|    5 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | new      |
|    6 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 | resolved |
|    7 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | open     |
|    8 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | new      |
|    9 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | open     |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE testin(vals varchar(100))
    ->  BEGIN
    ->     set @ul = vals;
    ->     set @qry = concat("select * from test where id IN(",@ul,")");    
    ->     prepare stmt from @qry;
    ->     execute stmt;    
    -> END;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> set @val = '3,4,6';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call testin(@val);
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| id   | created             | resolved            | status   |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|    3 | 2015-05-10 00:00:00 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00 | resolved |
|    4 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | open     |
|    6 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 | resolved |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```